# Строки на странице

Tags: html, html5, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте, как будет лучше реализовать текст, как на фото? Делать каждый ряд отдельным

или в цельном тексте расставлять  в нужных местах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выровнять текст на всю ширину

```
text-align:justify;
```

Comment: Нууу, это не совсем то что мне нужно

Comment: тогда уточните почему именно не то что нужно?

Comment: когда я ставлю тот стайл, который написали вы, текст у меня как вы и сказали выравниваеться на всю ширину, а мне нужны те два больших белых отступа слева и справа. или их при этом паддингом настраивать нужно?

Comment: ваш текст должен быть в котейнере тогда, оберните его в div со стилем max-width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; ширина 1000px это условно конечно же, установите такую какая вам нужна

Comment: точно! то что нужно, спасибо.